# How to process videos from google drive in google colab

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I have several videos on my google drive. I want to process convert these videos to audio (I already have code for this using ffmpeg). However, the videos are very long and I do not want to have to download them locally. Is there a way to process them on google colab without downloading each video locally?

I already a list of file id's I got using pydrive.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mount your Drive via:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/gdrive')
%cd /gdrive
```

Change your path accordingly, where `/gdrive` is your "home". Afterwards, you can load your data like you are used to on your local pc.